ElectronNET Electron.Dialog.ShowOpenDialogAsync never returns
Consider the following code:
private async Task ShowOpenFileDialogAsync()
{
    BrowserWindow? mainWindow = Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First();
    
    OpenDialogOptions options = new()
    {
        Title = "Choose a file",
        Properties = [OpenDialogProperty.openFile],
        Filters = [new FileFilter { Name = "JSON Files", Extensions = ["json"] }]
    };

    await Electron.Dialog.ShowOpenDialogAsync(mainWindow, options);
    
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}

This is called from Blazor like so:
<button @onclick="ShowOpenFileDialogAsync">Open</button>

This displays the open file dialog, but "done" is never printed to the console, indicating that Electron.Dialog.ShowOpenDialogAsync never returns anything.
Have I missed something somewhere? I can't seem to find any documentation about how to interact with dialogs to know whether this code is correct or not.
Note:

OS = macOS Sequoia
ElectronNET = version 23.6.2
App = Blazor Server .NET 8.0


Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the Console.WriteLine() and seeing if the break point is hit.  This will help isolate if your ShowOpenDialogAsync() is returning and the issue is with the Console line, or if it does not actually return.

@Kevin it has weirdly started working, so I'm not sure what the issue actually is. I think it might have something to do with the developer experience in Rider...it's a little buggy. I'm going to delete this question as it seems to relate to my machine, rather than to ElectronNET itself.

@Kevin specifically, when I stop and restart the app, it's not killing all the underlying processes properly, so when it runs a second time, I think the previously unclosed processes are causing problems.

@Matthew I provided you with a solution that will solve all of your underlying problems, including the ones mentioned in the comment section.

Problem analysis
The issues mentioned are the incapacity of the app not to close its underlying process and the incapacity of the app not to print information in the terminal, even if the code is implicitly stating that this action should be carried out. In order to determine the issue, an app according to the specifications mentioned in the issue's must be instantiated. The steps specified within the repository were followed and applied. The result is unsatisfactory because it results in errors saying that the app cannot communicate with NodeJS and when the window is closed, the underlying Electron process is not closed.
Solution
Even if in the official repository is mentioned that is supports .NET 8.0, the reality is that it barely supports this version. After switching the app to the version .NET 6.0, the app gives less errors, but it was still not displaying the Electron app window and it was still letting the underlying Electron process open after the application was closed. A further research was carried out in order to find a working sample of a Blazor Server + Electron application. After the sample was found, the reason for the previously mentioned issues was found too. The reason is that the application was not initialised properly.
//Program.cs

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseElectron(args);
            webBuilder.UseEnvironment("Development");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
    }

// Startup.cs

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });

            if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
            {
                CreateWindow();
            }
        }
        private async void CreateWindow()
        {
            var window = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync();
            window.OnClosed += () => {
                Electron.App.Quit();
            };
        }
    }

After I used the startup configuration shown above, the application was working smoothly and without errors. The cause for the basic operational errors was caused by the runtime version and the bad startup configuration, which were caused by a lack of information within the official documentation. The issue with the app not closing the underlying process was caused by the fact that the official documentation did not provide any information regarding the fact that an OnClosed event must be attached to the Electron window that will close the underlying Electron process when the application is closed.
        private async void CreateWindow()
        {
            var window = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync();
            window.OnClosed += () => {
                Electron.App.Quit();
            };
        }



Cause for the issues
A general lack of information and guidance that has to be provided within the official documentation.

Thank you for this detailed solution. This helped a lot!
